# Getting k most common tokens

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

I have two arrays: `x` contains the count of certain tokens in a dataset, and `tok` contains the corresponding token value for each count.

The 0th value of each looks like this, showing that token 4872 occurs twice, etc. for the 0th datapoint.

`print(x[0])`

`print(tok[0])`

[image]

**I would like to keep only the most common tokens (the k most common).**

I was thinking to sort the token values by number of times they occur in `tok` and then go through `x` and `tok` to remove those. But I don't know how to go about this.

**Edit:** some answers suggested doing the following, (I used 2 toy lists for demonstration) and they outputted counter objects but not the right ones:

```
prs = Counter(dict(zip([1,2,1,2,1,2],['a','b','c','a','a','b'])))
print(prs)
```

outputs

```
Counter({2: 'b', 1: 'a'})
```

while the result I want would be
`{'a': 4, 'b': 4, 'c': 1}`

Comment: Please try to not share images of text, paste it, that easier and nicer. Also that's MUCH better to share some code, your tries ;)

Comment: Why did you unaccept the answer ? ;)

Comment: @azro Oh it was giving the wrong counts so I unaccepted... But then I realized that your solution works for each ```x[i]``` and ```tok[i]``` individually so I adapted it to work for all of ```x``` and ```tok``` . so ultimately it was close enough:) accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip` to pair data, then a `Counter` to get the most common ones

```
from collections import Counter
x = [2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2]
tok = [123, 345, 3433, 3333, 335, 3334]

pairs = Counter(dict(zip(tok, x)))
```

Use `most_common()` to retrieve an descending sorted list by value, you can select the size, or all

```
top_x = pairs.most_common(3)
print(top_x)  # [(21443, 5), (14940, 4), (9179, 3)]

top_x = pairs.most_common()
print(top_x)  # [(335, 5), (3333, 4), (3433, 3), (123, 2), (3334, 2), (345, 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct.

A nice way to go about it is to

- Join the two lists into a single list in which each entry represents both the token and and the count.
- Sort according to the count.
- Take the k largest.

Python has the "zip" function to help us join two lists, and has the "sorted" function to help us sort.

A short solution (take the 5 highest) would look like this:

```
x = [4, 5, 8, 0, 9, 7, 0, 4, 1]
tok = [6734, 5675, 182436, 12506, 1395, 767, 45570, 134, 6521]

# 'sorted' sorts the list created by 'zip'. This works because the items are tuples,
# where the count is first. When you sort tuples, they are sorted by
# the first item, then second item, etc.
sorted(zip(x, tok), reverse=True)[:5]
```

This results in:

`[(9, 1395), (8, 182436), (7, 767), (5, 5675), (4, 6734)]`

which is what you want.

Extra note: if you explore how the `zip` function works, you'll see that since it returns an iterator you can't see the actual value just by running `zip(x, tok)`. In order to see the value it produces, you would need to do `list(zip(x, tok))`, where `list` is a function that converts an iterator into a list.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the note about ```list(zip)```